# Excel VBA Rows.Count and Rows(x) behavior

Tags: excel, vba, count, range, rows

I am trying to understand how to use Rows.Count property and Rows(x) method on Range objects:

I have the following range object:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("B66:B78")

rng.Rows.Count ---> returns 13
```

So, I am expecting `rng.Rows(15)`, to not return anything since, if I am understanding this right, row indices should equal row count and so should not be greater than 13(?). But `rng.Rows(15)` does return a `Range` object. Why is this?

Edit:

Here is my subroutine :

```
Sub Button2_Click()

Dim a As Range
Set a = Range("A1:C10")
Dim ginrng As Range
Set ginrng = a.Find("gin")
Debug.Print "Row " & ginrng.Row & ", B cell value = " & ginrng.Range("B" & ginrng.Row).Value
Dim b As String
b = ginrng.Address

Do
    Dim ginrngnxt As Range
    Set ginrng = a.FindNext(ginrng)
    Debug.Print "Row " & ginrng.Row & ", B cell value = " & ginrng.Range("B" & ginrng.Row).Value

Loop While b <> ginrng.Address


End Sub
```

Screenshot of dataset:

[image]

Screenshot of actual output from the subroutine:
[image]

The expected output from subroutine:

```
Row 2, B cell value = wafer
Row 3, B cell value = start
Row 4, B cell value = gin
Row 5, B cell value = may
Row 6, B cell value = go
Row 7, B cell value = gin
Row 9, B cell value = water
Row 10, B cell value = tonic
Row 2, B cell value = wafer
```

B cell values in the actual output don't match B cell values in the data set. Why is this?

Comment: There is an answer... but in the meantime, can you explain what you are trying to do? This may be an X-Y problem.

Comment: `rng.Rows(15)` can expand beyond your defined range. It will just mark the 15th row below your starting point of the range (`B66`). So, it looks like it will return the 80th row. Agreed with above that this is prob not the question you really want to ask. What is the problem with this behavior as it relates to your actual task is prob a more interesting question...

Comment: Updated OP with actual issue and supporting info.

Comment: Remove the first `ginrng.` from `ginrng.Range("B" & ginrng.Row)`.

Comment: In other words, in the Immediate Window, `? Range("A2").Range("B2").Address` returns `$B$3`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Range.Range
Range.Rows
Range.Columns
```

can be thought of returning a range *relative to* the starting point.

As an example:

```
With Range("A2")
     Debug.Print .Range("B2").Address '<~ returns $B$3
     Debug.Print .Rows(2).Address  '<~ returns $A$3
     Debug.Print .Columns(2).Address '~ returns $B$2
End With
```

In your specific case,

```
ginrng.Range("B" & ginrng.Row).Value
```

gives you a range relative to `ginrng`. If `ginrng` is `A2`, then

```
ginrng.Range("B" & ginrng.Row)
```

is equivalent to

```
Range("A2").Range("B2")
```

which is actually cell `$B$3`, not `$B$2`.

In other words, remove the starting `ginrng.`, and now `Range("B" & ginrng.Row).Value` will *actually* be in column B, and in the same row as `ginrng`.

Comment: this solution works if the dataset is in the same workbook as the subroutine. When the dataset is in an external workbook, how do I fix it?

Comment: Make sure you fully qualify the workbook and worksheet the range is in/on.